# ng-disable a button if ng-pattern of input does not match

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to disable a button with ng-disable if ng-pattern of an input field does not match the regular expression. In this case the regular expression is "[0-9]". I have tried the following code:

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="Filter">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ASCII" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Test.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="ctrl" ng-controller="Ctrl">
          Text <input type="text" ng-model="input_field" ng-pattern="[0-9]"><br/>
          <button ng-disabled="input_field.$valid">Start Filter</button>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Test.js

```
Module.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
    $scope.input_field = "Insert your Text here!";
}
```

Unfortunately it is not working. I have tried many ways but nothing worked. Do you have any ideas how to disable the button if the pattern do not match.

Comment: You've got your Booleans mixed. `ng-disabled="input_field.$valid"` means that the button will be disabled if the input field is valid.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should wrap it with `<form>` and fix the syntax: `$error` instead of `$valid`, `[0-9]` -> `/^[0-9]/`. Here is a demo, adjust it appropriately:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form name="myForm">
      Input: <input type="text" ng-model="input_field" name="input_field" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]/" placeholder="Insert a number"><br/>
      <button ng-disabled="myForm.input_field.$error.pattern || !input_field">Start Filter</button>
    </form>

  </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {});
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its working now but i have changed the pattern to "/^[0-9]+$/" instead of "/^[0-9]/"

Comment: @Lehtim well it was a quick sketch, It was easier to select $error if I had a form as well, so as long as it works, it's all good. The pattern can easily be changed, even dynamically (if you assign it to a scoped variable)